# Imagen de fondo de div no respeta normas de ajuste de imagen de CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Buenas!

Estoy elaborando una página web para un proyecto personal, y tengo dificultades cuando quiero añadir una función nueva.

La página es sencillamente una tabla con dos celdas y un div en cada una de ellas. El de la izquierda es el menu y el de la derecha la información. En el susodicho div, intento que la imagen de fondo cambie cada vez que entro, eligiendo aletoriamente entre los 10 fondos que tengo.

El HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prj</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<script src="scripts/rd_background.js"></script>


    <table border="0" class="master">
            <tbody>
                <td class="left">
                    <div class="dleft">
                        <table border="0" class="slave">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img src="images/logo-white.png" alt="PIOCAM 2018" style="width:135px;height:130px;" class="logo"></img></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tdmenu"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="right">
                    <div class="dright" id="jsBg" >
                    <script type="text/javascript">randBg();</script>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>

</body>
```

El CSS (sólo enseño el CSS con el cual JavaScript interactúa, el resto no tiene que ver con la funcionalidad.).

```
div.dright {
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
    background: url("images/bg/3.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 91vh; 
 }
```

Y el JavaScript.

```
var bgCount = 10;

function randBg() {
    var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * bgCount );
    document.getElementById('jsBg').style.background = 'url("images/bg/"+num+".jpg")'; 
}
```

He analizado todo el código en base a mis conocimientos, he buscado en google y sigo sin entender el problema.

Si alguien es tan amable de decirme por qué la imagen no se cambia aleatoriamente y corregirme el fallo, se lo agradezco. Gracias de antemano.

(Update) **Problema solucionado**, pero no del todo.

La causa del problema residía en el código del javascript:

Antes.

```
'url("images/bg/"+num+".jpg")';
```

Después.

```
'url("images/bg/'+num+'.jpg")';
```

Un simple error de comillas. Ahora la solución ha generado un problema: la imagen no respeta *background-size: cover;* *background-repeat: no-repeat;*, ni *background-position: center;*. La imagen se posiciona automáticamente sin respetar esas líneas de CSS.

Comment: Hola spund3. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has hecho logs para ver que puede estar sucediendo?  Te da erroes por consola? Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b no, no me da señales de error.

Comment: Que nombre tienen tus imagenes?

Comment: enumeradas, del 1 al 10 @LuisFernando

Comment: ¿Estás llamando a la función  randBg() en el body onLoad() ??

Comment: Intenta usando el id para dar los estilos

Comment: @Risa__B ¿cómo?

Answer (score 1):

Dato: tiene error cuando concatenabas el nombre de la imagen, recuerda que la extension de la imagen debe ser la misma que definas alli. (todas deben ser PNG; o todas JPG , etc)

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Prj</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        div.dright {
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
        background: url("img/03.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        opacity: 0.5;
        height: 91vh; 
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
     }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="randBg();">


      <table border="0" class="master">
        <tbody>
          <td class="left">
            <div class="dleft">
              <table border="0" class="slave">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><img src="img/bac_logo.PNG" alt="PIOCAM 2018" style="width:135px;height:130px;" class="logo"></img></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tdmenu"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="right">
            <div class="dright" id="jsBg" >
            </div>
          </td>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var bgCount = 10;

    function randBg() {
        var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * bgCount );
        document.getElementById('jsBg').style.background = 'url("img/'+num+'.PNG")'; 
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega en el css un `width` y `height` para el div y borra opciones de background (estan sobrando):

```
div.dright {
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width:91vh;
  height:91vh;
}
```

Borra esta linea del `html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">randBg();</script>
```

Corrige la funcion `randBg()` tiene un problema de apostrofes y falta propiedades de imagen. Agrega la funcion `randBg();` al final

```
function randBg() {
  var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * bgCount );
  document.getElementById('jsBg').style.background = 'url("images/bg/'+num+'.jpg") no-repeat center';
}
//aqui invocas
randBg();
```

Comment: las opciones de width y height cambian lo que no deben cambiar...

Comment: tambien tienes un problemas en **'url("images/bg/'+num+'.jpg")';** +num+ debe estar entre apostrofes no comillas

Comment: ajuste la respuesta, con algunos ajustes para la imagen. Pusiste *height=91hv* tambien debes poner *width*

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es eso:
Tienes que poner el script en la etiqueta head, y después en la etiqueta body, poner un onLoad =  "randBg()":

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prj</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="scripts/rd_background.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="randBg()"> 
    <table border="0" class="master">
            <tbody>
                <td class="left">
                    <div class="dleft">
                        <table border="0" class="slave">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img src="images/logo-white.png" alt="PIOCAM 2018" style="width:135px;height:130px;" class="logo"></img></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tdmenu"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="right">
                    <div class="dright" id="jsBg" >
                    <script type="text/javascript">randBg();</script>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>

</body>
```